# Industry's authenticated person could be contacted by admission committee like professors (who given me lor)

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, industry

I have an industry 4 years industry experience after masters. Now I want to do PhD in USA.

My question is that PhD admission committee will cross verify my industry experience letter by contacting the industry's govern body(like GM, MD etc.) ?

Answer (score 3):

That is unlikely in US, unless you give specific permission for it. Other than "Yes AM was employed here" they aren't likely to say much for various reasons including company policy and privacy considerations.

Instead, if you want such things to happen, you ask someone (a superior, say) to write a letter of recommendation for you.

And "industry's governing body" isn't a real concept here except in a few cases.

And, in general, an admissions committee looks only at what you, the candidate, present in your application materials. They aren't likely to go outside that, again for several reasons including time.

See also: [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368)